# How to leave/exit/deactivate a node virtual environment?

Tags: node.js

I'm using virtual environment in node .

```
rails@rails:~/React$ source env/bin/activate 
(env)rails@rails:~/React$
rails@rails:~/React$
```

However, how do I exit from virtual machines and workon my real machine again? What the way I have of getting back to

```
rails@rails:~/React$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 deactivate_node
```

**You can deactivate the node environment by the following command**

```
rails@rails:~/React$deactivate_node
```

**To install and activate the nodeenv use following command:**

> After installing nodejs

```
$sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

> Install nodeenv

```
$sudo apt-get install nodeenv
```

> If want to create the environment in the directory then create one by:
>   for example:

```
rails@rails:~/React$mkdir react_demo
rails@rails:~/React$cd react_demo


rails@rails:~/React/react_demo$ nodeenv envs
```

> now we can activate the environment.

```
rails@rails:~/React/react_demo$source envs/bin/activate
```

> To deactivate

```
(envs)rails@rails:~/React/react_demo$deactivate_node
```